# What is the difference between URLRequest and URL?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

I am using `URLSession` to download file. Two methods are there:

```
downloadTask(with request: URLRequest)
```

and

```
downloadTask(with url: URL).
```

What is difference between the two? Apart from POST, PUT, is there any special use for simple download?

Comment: `with url:` is a helper that will create the request for you with some default settings.

Comment: In `URLRequest` you can put method (POST, PUT, etc. while with a simple URL, by default it will be a get), you can use bodyData (could be quite useful for POST params for instance), and other property you can set on a URLRequest.

Comment: I truly don't understand the downvotes to this question. Maybe the only thing they wanted was for you to show some effort of what you've tried doing. But I don't see that mentioned in the comments...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation on URLRequest states:

> A URL load request that is independent of protocol or URL scheme.

That can be found here: [URL Request Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest)

What the essentially means is that with a **URL** you get the iOS default behavior for all the properties of the URL and how it loads something.

With the **URLRequest** you get fine grained control over things like caching, protocol, cookies, and state.